# outlook 2003 rejects correct password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, password-management

I have outlook on 2 computers, both with windows 7.  On one computer, it keeps asking for a password.  I enter the correct password, but it does not change anything.  It asks again.  This is the computer with my complete address book, naturally.  Outlook is completely non-functional.  I had this problem several times before, but forgot how it was corrected.  Much gratitude to person who can solve this problem.

Comment: What domain? Often this can happen if the provider needs you to confirm security or policy updates. Is this Gmail, outlook, gmx, yahoo... Can you log in via their Web portal

Comment: Outlook 2003....

Comment: That is not a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Do you change password recently? 
This could be related with incorrectly cached password in Credential Manager. 
To fix this, please go to Control Panel > Credential Manager > Windows Credential. Locate that has Outlook in the name. Click the name to expand the set of credentials, and then click Remove.

We can also remove and then re-add your email account to Outlook.

Besides, I find one link here which should be useful to you: [Why does Outlook keep prompting for password](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook)

Comment: I did not change passwords.  This recommended fix did not work.  Very frustrating.  Thanks for trying.